# Karatsuba Multiplication - Wrong output when solving AD+BC

Tags: integers

So I've only been introduced to Karatsuba's method for integer multiplication. I started working through some examples, and everything was fine until I hit the following multiplication problem:

---

---

Key/Expressions:

$n = $ max digits from the two integer inputs (+1 in the case of odd numbers - adds leading zero)

$m = n/2$

$x.y = 10^n(a.c) + 10^m(a.d+b.c) + b.d$

$a.d+b.c = (a+b)(c+d) - a.c - b.d$

---

---

Input arguments:

$x = 107$

$y = 102$

---

$n = 4$

$m = 2$

---

$a = 01$

$b = 07$

$c = 01$

$d = 02$

---

Solving $a.c$ and $b.d$ for above $x.y$ expression:

$a.c = 1$

$b.d = 14$

---

Solving $ad+bc$ for $x.y$ expression:

$a.d+b.c = (a+b)(c+d) - a.c - b.d$

$a.d+b.c = (7)(2) – 1 – 14$

$a.d+b.c = -1$ ***(solution should be 9 here!)***

---

This is where my problem occurs. As stated in the wiki article TonyK linked:

$z_{1}=x_{1}y_{0}+x_{0}y_{1}$

$z_{1}=(x_{1}+x_{0})(y_{1}+y_{0})-x_{1}y_{1}-x_{0}y_{0}$

But this is producing the wrong output for me. Would be great to know where I'm going wrong. Like I said, I've successfully solved other multiplication problems using this method, but this one is giving problems.

Comment: It's difficult to know where you went wrong, because this doesn't look like Karatsuba at all. I suggest you look at the example in [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), which has $A=12, B=345, C=6, D=789$.

Comment: It's just a step-by-step for a 3-digit karatsuba multiplication, given 107 and 102 as the two integer inputs. I left out the x.y expression and m (which is just n/2) and just solved for A.C, B.D and AD+BC. It was at AD+BC where I ran into the issue, so I stopped there and didn't finish the multiplication.

Comment: @TonyK I'm not sure why the question is receiving downvotes, but I'll update it with more info. I've successfully used Karatsuba to solve a number of integer multiplication problems, but this is the only one that seems to not work. Maybe if someone could give their own solution it would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $(7)(2)$ should be $(A+B)\cdot(C+D)=(8)(3)$.

Comment: Wow! Now that's embarrassing. Thanks